# Can we create dynamic XFA form using iText / PDFBox or any other PDF library in java?

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext, pdfbox

I want to create my custom dynamic XFA pdf form using iText or PDFBox.

For example, purchase order form given here, 
[Populate dynamic XFA pdf form itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508342/populate-dynamic-xfa-pdf-form-itext)

I want to generate such PDF form using java library.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: As @Bruno already answered, there is no highlevel support for creating XFA forms in iText or PDFBox. On the other hand the XFA specification is public. Thus, you can try and generate the XML manually and inject this XML. Doing so should be possible using either lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the creation of XFA documents is not supported using iText or PDFBox. There are plans to start a project that would allow you to create XDP templates at iText Group, but there is no ETA as to when it will be ready.